# How to change Android TitleBar style?

Tags: android, styles, themes, titlebar

I am using Holo aplication theme. I have the following title bar:

[image: Screenshot #1]

How can I change it (without changing the aplication theme) to this one (no padding and icon):

[image: Screenshot #2]

Which one is default title bar in Android 4.1?

Comment: So basically you want to have custom title bar? Right? If yes, then there are lots of tutorials that can teach you that.. See [first](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/), [second](http://help.discretelogix.com/android/how-to-add-custom-title-bar-to-android-application.htm), [third](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar) Hope they help

Comment: No. It is not custom TitleBar. It is default one for some theme but I am not sure for which one...